# How to implement a "Loading in phases" animation like google does in its samples

Tags: android

Google gives nice examples of material design implementations, but doesn't provide any clue on how to program them.

I'm particularity interested in [this "Loading in phases" sample](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/progress-activity.html#progress-activity-behavior), but I don't see how to start with to implements this kind of "floating" progress bar.

Comment: Are you asking how to load in phases or how to do that animation?  Those are two completely different things.

Comment: Your question is broad, in the sense we cant tell if you want to use the loading animation, or if you want to load an `CursorAdapter` (for example), and then alter it, and notify that the data set was changed (and thus re-render screen/listview)

Comment: Sorry, I mean how to implement the animation. I changed the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to implement this animation explicitly. You can just put RecyclerView into SwipeRefreshLayout and in `SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener` call notifyItemInserted method from adapter. Just like this:

```
public void onRefresh() {
    //position is zero just for add item at beginning of list
    int position = 0;
    values.add(position, new Item());
    adapter.notifyItemInserted(position);
}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

Comment: Thank you, SwipeRefreshLayout is what I was missing. Why isn't there any link to the useful apis in google samples.

Comment: You can find a full code example here: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/swiperefreshlayout.php